# Add Windows User Account to Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Ubuntu Server v. 13.04 that I am using as a file server (amongst it being a LAMP stack).

I have a samba share let's call it `/shares/SQLDatabases`

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server in the same network, with this share already mapped as a network drive.  On it, I am running SQL Server 2012 (because I have to for certain projects).

All my databases are stored in the samba share as listed above, and what I've tried is as follows:

```
DBCC TraceOn(1807);

EXEC sp_attach_db 
@dbname = N'Cloud.CMS',
@filename1 = N'\\192.168.2.98\ServerStorage\Database\Cloud.CMS.mdf',
@filename2 = N'\\192.168.2.98\ServerStorage\Database\Cloud.CMS_log.ldf';

DBCC TraceOff(1807);
```

But am getting the following back:

```
Directory lookup for the file "\\192.168.2.98\ServerStorage\Database\Cloud.CMS.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
```

My assumptions are that I need to add my `MSSQLSERVER` account on my Ubuntu box, question is how do I do this?

Comment: Do you already have Samba configured for other shares/services?  Do you actually have a Active Directory Domain?  If you joined the linux box to the AD, then you wouldn't need to create an account on the Linux side.

Comment: No active directory, yes, Samba is configured for other shares, and yes I did just create the user on Linux, and the same issue arises

Comment: One thing I notice.  Even though my default data storage directory has the MSSQLSERVER user added, windows user management does not list the account

Comment: Wouldn't you get poor performance accessing a database over SMB anyway? But I would suggest that whichever account your SQL server instance runs under would need to have access to the share.

Comment: drive is a highend SSD, attached in a gigabit lan, with high-end machines.  Performance is not an issue (in comparison, I have another machine that serves video files at 1080i, without issue)

Comment: @o7thWebDesign OK, but streaming and SMB are completely different. If you have already used this and not had issues then fine, but if not you could be in for a shock.

Comment: @o7theWebDesign Try this article for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2011/10/18/sql-databases-on-file-shares-it-s-time-to-reconsider-the-scenario.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Look man, I understand the concepts behind sharing, SMB, and the potential pitfalls of doing this, and I am not concerned about it.  None of the comments you have posted are constructive nor conducive to the question at hand

Comment: @o7thwebdesign That's not true, I suggested that the SQL service would have to run as an account with access to the share. This is what you ended up doing no? Relax, man. People here are only trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cured this by creating a new user account on my Windows machine that matched the credentials of an account on the linux box, then changed the account that MSSQLSERVER service runs under to that new account.

More info on it and procedures I took to complete.

http://o7thblog.com/sql-2012-linux-shared-data-file-storage